# Facebook SDK not public for visiters

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, sdk

I made an FB.api that get the last 2 posts of my facebook page. I added it to my personal website. It works on my website, but when someone else visit my website they can't see my last posts...When I googled the problem, I saw my FB app need to be live. So I did it. But it still doesn't work...

Here is my code:

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
        FB.init({
            appId: 'APP_ID', // App ID
            status: true, // check login status
            cookie: true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
            xfbml: true // parse XFBML
        });

    };

    function toonID() {
        FB.api('/PAGE_ID/feed?limit=2', function (response) {
            var str = "";
            for (var i = 0; i < response.data.length; i++) {
                //console.log(i + " : " + response.data[i].message);
                //str += "<b>id: </b>" + response.data[i].id.slice(16) + "<br><br />";
                str += "<div class='fb-post' data-href='https://www.facebook.com/Beatpounce/posts/" + response.data[i].id.slice(16) + "' data-width='466'></div><br /><br />";
            }
            document.getElementById("post").innerHTML = str;
        });
    }
```

I think I need an acces_token but I don't know how to use

Comment: "it doesn´t work" is not a sufficient error description, please debug your code and try to find out where exactly the problem is.

Comment: An access token is required to request this resource. That's the error..

Answer (score 0):

You need to use at least an App Token for the call - but you should do that API call server side, because the App Token includes your App Secret and you should never reveal your App Secret on the client. User [PHP cURL](http://php.net/manual/book.curl.php) for that call and add your App Token as `access_token` parameter.

More information about Tokens:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens
- http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-access-tokens/